# Electron: TypeError: Cannot create property 'default' on symbol 'Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)'

Tags: node.js, electron, graphql, packager

I've developed an electron app with following tech stack:

- NodeJS (10.15) with Babel to allow ES6 import/export syntax.
- Sequelize on SQLite and GraphQL to handle an internal database.
- ReactJS (bundled) for views.

I've configured everything to work with Electron and running "electron" command in project root folder works without errors.

Now i'm trying to distribute it using this tutorial: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-distribution

So i've simply downloaded the 4.1.4 binaries for windows and moved the project folder under resources/app/

But running the electron.exe i've the following error:

```
App threw an error during load
TypeError: Cannot create property 'default' on symbol 'Symbol(nodejs.util.inspect.custom)'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\myapp\resources\app\node_modules\graphql\jsutils\nodejsCustomInspectSymbol.js:18:84)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\myapp\resources\app\node_modules\graphql\jsutils\nodejsCustomInspectSymbol.js:20:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\workspace\myapp\resources\app\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\workspace\myapp\resources\app\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\myapp\resources\app\node_modules\graphql\jsutils\defineToJSON.js:8:57)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\myapp\resources\app\node_modules\graphql\jsutils\defineToJSON.js:36:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:30)
    at Module._compile (C:\workspace\myapp\resources\app\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:83:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:722:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\workspace\myapp\resources\app\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:88:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

i've also tried to run npx electron resources/app/ from binaries folder and i've got the same error.
So i think the issue is something about the paths.

i've also tried electron-packager and the error is the same because this tool does the same process of guide above.

What can i do to fix it?

UPDATE1: after some investigations i've found that babel causes the issues. I guess when you run a project from a parent folder. I'm trying to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

i've solved using this kind of configuration for babel/register:

```
const rootPath=path.resolve(path.join(__dirname, "../../"));

require("@babel/register")({
    root: rootPath,
    extends: path.join(rootPath, '.babelrc'),
    ignore: [/node_modules/],
    only: [rootPath],
})
```